# Getting error "Specified file failed upload test" when adding file from Base64 decode

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I have searched everywhere online and cannot find a solution.

I am attempting to use `wp_handle_upload()` but I am getting "Specified file failed upload test", only when I try to upload a file that I created from `base64_decode()`;

I am pretty sure this is not a permissions or a server issue. Here are some more notes:

- everything works fine when uploading files on WordPress to the media library
- my code even works when I get the files directly from `$_FILES`. It stopped working when I started having to create my own `$file` array.
- I have another live version of this on a completely different server and the problem is the same
- I have tried `'image/png'` and `'image/jpg'` for the file type.
- I was using the uploads directory for the `tmp_name` but that didnt make a difference
- The temporary file **is** succesfully uploading

**More Info:** I added the line `print_r( is_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] ));die;` to line 822 in /wp-admin/includes/file.php. I believe its because this is coming back as false that error is being thrown.

```
    $upload_dir       = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_path      = get_stylesheet_directory().'/tmp-images/';
    $img = $_POST['main_image_0'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $decoded          = base64_decode($img) ;
    $filename         = $_POST['file_name'];
    $hashed_filename  = md5( $filename . microtime() ) . '_' . $filename;

    // @new
    if (!is_dir($upload_path)) {
        // dir doesn't exist, make it
        mkdir('upload/promotions/' . $month);
    }
    
    $image_upload     = file_put_contents( $upload_path . $hashed_filename, $decoded );

    //HANDLE UPLOADED FILE
    if( !function_exists( 'wp_handle_sideload' ) ) {
      require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }

    // Without that I'm getting a debug error!?
    if( !function_exists( 'wp_get_current_user' ) ) {
      require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php' );
    }

    // @new
    $file             = array();
    $file['error']    = 0;
    $file['tmp_name'] = $upload_path . $hashed_filename;
    $file['name']     = $filename;
    $file['type']     = 'image/jpeg';
    $file['size']     = filesize( $upload_path . $hashed_filename );        
    
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

    $file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );
    print_r($file);print_r($file_return);die;
```

This returns

```
Array
(
    [error] => 0
    [tmp_name] => /var/www/example/wp-content/themes/mytheme/tmp-images/eea84bdc7b9b79a10898425c79f62fc2_20130202_173509.jpg
    [name] => 20130202_173509.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [size] => 273444
)
Array
(
    [error] => Specified file failed upload test.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this. It was due to the function using `is_uploaded_file` [which is specifically designed to handle HTTP POST requests](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php). So everything was working the way it should be. I just did not realise `wp_handle_upload()` was only for this  purpose.  I had used base64 and converted this before calling the  function which meant it was no longer processing a file from a post request.

To solve my issue I instead used `wp_upload_bits` ([ref](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_bits/)).